# get_terms with posts that have a different taxonomy with term x

Tags: taxonomy, terms, tax-query

Here's the situation;

I am using get_terms to retrieve all terms from **Tax 1** with posts associated with it. Using the following

```
$args = array(
            'hide_empty'    =>  0,
            'orderby'       =>  'name',
            'taxonomy'      =>  'tax_1'
        );

$terms  =   get_terms( $args );
```

Pretty simple. However that returns all terms, and does not consider the second taxonomy **Tax 2** which I want to compare against **term x**

Ultimately I want to get all **Tax 1 terms** that have posts which also have **Tax 2 term x**

I could most likely to a query directly on posts and create an array of terms where the post has both of the above but that seems a bit messy, I am hoping there is a way to query this directly.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Just to start, you say *"I am using get_terms to retrieve all terms from Tax 1 with posts associated with it"*, however your actual code gets all terms in that taxonomy regardless of whether or not they have posts. You need to set `hide_empty` to `true`.

So with that out of the way, the bad news: You won't be able to do this with `get_terms()`. That type of information doesn't exist without querying posts and comparing the terms. So the messy solution you wanted to avoid is unfortunately necessary.

Ultimately I think this is a situation where you might be better off just using SQL. This code will use `$wpdb` to get terms from Taxonomy A that have any posts of a given post type that have a specific term in Taxonomy B:

```
$post_type  = 'post';
$taxonomy_a = 'post_tag';
$taxonomy_b = 'category';
$term_b_id  = 12;

$query = $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT DISTINCT
        terms.*
    FROM
        `wp_terms` terms
    INNER JOIN
        `wp_term_taxonomy` tt1 ON
            tt1.term_id = terms.term_id
    INNER JOIN
        `wp_term_relationships` tr1 ON
            tr1.term_taxonomy_id = tt1.term_taxonomy_id
    INNER JOIN
        `wp_posts` p ON
            p.ID = tr1.object_id
    INNER JOIN 
        `wp_term_relationships` tr2 ON
            tr2.object_ID = p.ID
    INNER JOIN 
        `wp_term_taxonomy` tt2 ON
            tt2.term_taxonomy_id = tr2.term_taxonomy_id
    WHERE
        p.post_type = %s AND
        p.post_status = 'publish' AND
        tt1.taxonomy = %s AND
        tt2.taxonomy = %s AND
        tt2.term_id = %d",
    [
        $post_type,
        $taxonomy_a,
        $taxonomy_b,
        $term_b_id,
    ]
);

$results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );

if ( $results ) {
    $terms = array_map( 'get_term', $results );
}
```

So that code gets all *Tags* that have *Posts* that are assigned to the *Category* with the ID *12*.

The last little bit with `get_term()` ensures that the final array contains the same `WP_Term` objects that you would get by running `get_terms()`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the tax_query argument, for example:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'tax1',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $terms,
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'tax2',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $terms,
    )
)
```

To get all posts which have both terms. You can then use get_terms and pass the `object_ids` as a parameter. See the [WP_Term_Query documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/) for more details.