# display post count in archive page that have relation with another taxonomy term

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, terms, count

This topic has been ask in Stackexchange many times. But most of question unanswered or has incomplete answer. My custom post type **"Product"** and *two different taxonomy* **"Sectors"** and **"Seasons"**. Now I want to display product ***count for Garden archive page*** ( garden is the term of sectors taxonomy)  that ***have realtion with Winter*** ( winter is the term of seasons taxonomy). I did all my best during these 3 days but I can not solve this problem. Please help me. thanks for your attention. This is also a good source but can make it works https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/327150/196375

```
$sectors = get_queried_object();

$season = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'seasons',
    'hide_empty' => true,
    'fields' =>  '58', // winter term id
) );


foreach ($current_taxs as $current_tax) {

foreach ($seasons as $seasons) {

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
 'post_status'=>'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $current_tax,
            'field'    => 'slug',
           'terms'    => array( $current_tax ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'season',
            'field'    => 'slug',
           'terms'    => array( $season ),
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

echo $query->post_count;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION

```
  <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
     'post_status'=>'publish',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'sectors',
                'field'    => 'slug',
               'terms'    => 'garden',
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'season',
                'field'    => 'slug',
               'terms'    => 'winter',
            ),
        ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    echo $query->post_count ;
    
    
    
    ?>
```